# Delphi tclientdataset .cds datetime binary timeformat unpack

Tags: delphi, parsing, datetime, tclientdataset

I am trying to parse .cds delphi database file. Simple int values and strings are easy to parse. But the only one i cannot understand is a DateTime format.
I found 6 bytes that affecting DateTime Value

I am using python and the following code:

```
data = '\x00\x00' + '\xBC\xCE\x6F\xEC\xE7\xCC'
data_long = struct.unpack('Q', data)[0]
```

But struct.unpack doesnt have 6 byte type values, so i added \x00 \x00 to make 8 byte long value ('Q' option)

Here is small sample .cds file with one row https://yadi.sk/d/PkZKy50YgCmqE

> DateTimeIssl value = "16.04.2015 9:25:47"

I found 6 hex values but cant unpack it properly. 
Can anyone tell me how to read it, or maybe give me a link to some documentation about .cds file structure?

**Update:**
OK! Thanks to Deltics for guide me how to read TDateTime. I found some test values on internet and i wrote decode function that converts it to Python datetime object.

```
data = '\x2E\xD8\x82\x2D\xCE\x47\xE3\x40'

data_double = struct.unpack('d', data)[0]
double_split = str(data_double).split('.')

SECONDS_IN_DAY = 60*60*24
time_from_starting_date = timedelta(days=int(double_split[0]), seconds=int(SECONDS_IN_DAY * (float(double_split[1]) * pow(0.1, len(double_split[1])))))

starting_date = datetime(1899, 12, 30)
result_date = starting_date + time_from_starting_date

print time_from_starting_date
print result_date
```

> For **2E D8 82 2D CE 47 E3 40** it will be **08.02.2008 10:38:00**.
>   Works fine.

But i still cannot found valid 8-bytes for field **DateTimeIssl** in file that i've linked above. Maybe there a different  datetime format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responding to myself. Maybe for someone it will be useful.
In binary format, TClientDataSet DateTime contains **INTEGER** value of milliseconds since 02.01.0001, but stores as a 8-byte **DOUBLE**
So you have to read 8-bytes, unpack it as a double, then convert value to integer. Here is Python code that worked for me:

```
data = '\x00\xBC\xCE\x6F\xEC\xE7\xCC\x42'  # Time: 2015-04-16 09:25:47
data_double = struct.unpack('d', data)[0]

time_from_starting_date = timedelta(days=-2, milliseconds=long(data_double))
starting_date = datetime(0001, 01, 02)
result_date = starting_date + time_from_starting_date

print "Time:", result_date
```

Answer (score 5):

A Delphi date/time (TDateTime) is a Double precision floating point.  This is an 8-byte value.  You should not need to add any packing or null bytes.  If you are having to do this then you have not identified the double value correctly in the file.

Looking at the sample CDS you linked to, each value that could sensibly be interpreted as a date/time (e.g. DateRoshd, DateTimeIssl) is followed by 8 bytes of data.

After reading the double value, the whole number part of this value indicates the date as the number of days since 30 Dec 1899.  The decimal part is the time of day on that date.

e.g.

```
1.0 = 31 Dec 1899, 00:00 (midnight)
2.5 =  1 Jan 1900, 12:00 (midday)
```

[More information on the Delphi TDateTime data type can be found here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TDateTime).

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Can you please give me exact 8-bytes hex values for filed **DateTimeIssl**? With your help i successfully unpack other TDateTime values found on internet. But cant unpack values from my file. 
I updated my post for more information